# Java lambdas and streams to map

Tags: java, java-stream

I have this class:

```
package ProcessInvoices;

public class ProcessInvoices {

private final int partNumber;
private final String partDescription;
private int quantity;
private double price;

// constructor
public ProcessInvoices(int partNumber, String partDescription, int quantity, double price) {
    if (quantity < 0) // validate quantity
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Quantity must be >= 0");
    }

    if (price < 0.0) // validate price
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Price per item must be >= 0");
    }

    this.partNumber = partNumber;
    this.partDescription = partDescription;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.price = price;
} // end constructor

// get part number
public int getPartNumber() {
    return partNumber; // should validate
}

// get description
public String getPartDescription() {
    return partDescription;
}

// set quantity
public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    if (quantity < 0) // validate quantity
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Quantity must be >= 0");
    }

    this.quantity = quantity;
}

// get quantity
public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

// set price per item
public void setPrice(double price) {
    if (price < 0.0) // validate price
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Price per item must be >= 0");
    }

    this.price = price;
}

// get price per item
public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

// return String representation of ProcessInvoices object
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format(
            "Part #: %-2d  Description: %-15s  Quantity: %-4d  Price: $%,6.2f",
            getPartNumber(), getPartDescription(),
            getQuantity(), getPrice());
}

}
```

And this is the Driver:

```
package ProcessInvoices;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ProcessInvoicesDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ProcessInvoices[] Invoice = {
        new ProcessInvoices(83, "Electric sander", 7, 57.98),
        new ProcessInvoices(24, "Power saw", 18, 99.99),
        new ProcessInvoices(7, "Sledge hammer", 11, 21.50),
        new ProcessInvoices(77, "Hammer", 76, 11.99),
        new ProcessInvoices(39, "Lawn mower", 3, 79.50),
        new ProcessInvoices(68, "Screwdriver", 106, 6.99),
        new ProcessInvoices(56, "Jig saw", 21, 11.00),
        new ProcessInvoices(3, "Wrench", 34, 7.50)};

    List<ProcessInvoices> list = Arrays.asList(Invoice);


    ////////////////////////////////////////Invoices sorted by part description
    Function<ProcessInvoices, String> desc = ProcessInvoices::getPartDescription;
    Comparator<ProcessInvoices> byPartDesc = Comparator.comparing(desc);

    System.out.printf("%nInvoices sorted by part description:%n");
    list.stream().sorted(byPartDesc).forEach(System.out::println);

    ///////////////////////////Invoices sorted by price
    Function<ProcessInvoices, Double> price = ProcessInvoices::getPrice;
    Comparator<ProcessInvoices> byPrice = Comparator.comparing(price);

    System.out.printf("%nInvoices sorted by price:%n");
    list.stream().sorted(byPrice).forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.printf("\n");

    ///////////////// This Part Below is what i need help with ///// 
    Function<ProcessInvoices, Integer> quantity = ProcessInvoices::getQuantity;

    Comparator<ProcessInvoices> byquantity = Comparator.comparing(quantity);

    // display only first and last names
    System.out.printf("%nInvoices mapped to description and quantity:%n");
    list.stream()
            .sorted(byquantity)
            .map(ProcessInvoices::getPartDescription)
            .forEach(System.out::println);

}

}
```

On the driver where it says" this part i need help" how can i do this:

> Use lambdas and streams to map each Invoice to its PartDescription and Quantity, sort the results by Quantity, then display the results.

and it outputs like this:

```
Invoices mapped to description and quantity:
Description: Lawn mower       Quantity: 3
Description: Electric sander  Quantity: 7
Description: Sledge hammer    Quantity: 11
Description: Power saw        Quantity: 18
Description: Jig saw          Quantity: 21
Description: Wrench           Quantity: 34
Description: Hammer           Quantity: 76
Description: Screwdriver      Quantity: 106
```

I have done many things and i cant get it to work: what i have in the script above is the last thing i have tried.

Comment: From the list "list" i need to map the getPartDescription and getQuantity and sort by quantity. i have done that but it only prints PartDescription and not quantity.

Answer (score 0):

This reads a bit like a homework question so make sure you're not violating your school's honor code by asking for help here.

As far as an answer goes you can try something like this:

```
list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(desc,quantity,(q1,q2) -> q1 + q2)))
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
    .forEach(e -> System.out.println(String.format("Description: %-15s  Quantity: %-4d",e.getKey(),e.getValue())));
```

The collect statement converts the stream to a map of description,quantity, then the resulting entry set is sorted and printed. The (q1,q2)-> q1 + q2 expression is the logic used to handle a merge if the list contains duplicate descriptions. In this case I assumed that combining the result should be the sum of the two quantities. If it is an error for the input list to contain duplicates you can just use the two argument version of Collections.toMap() which will throw an exception if a duplicate key is encountered.

For more information on Collections.toMap(...) you can read the Java 8 javadocs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something similar to this example here, it can even work with what you have now:

```
System.out.println("Invoices sorted by part description:"); 

Arrays.stream(invoices)          
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(Invoice::getPartDescription))          
.forEach(System.out::println);
```